# UIAlertController willDismiss alternative

Tags: iphone, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I haven't done much iOS development in a while and while updating an old project I came across a question I couldn't find an answer for.

What is the replacement for

`actionSheet:willDismissWithButtonIndex:`

(emphasis on WILL)

I have some animation code that needs to execute at this point and currently I can only see how to execute my code after the sheet has been dismissed.

I'm sure the answer is right in front of my face, I just can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom UIAlertController with a delgate and use that

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol CustomAlertControllerDelegate {
@objc optional func CustomAlertControllerWillDismiss(controller:     CustomAlertController)
}


class CustomAlertController: UIAlertController {

weak var delegate:CustomAlertControllerDelegate?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.delegate?.CustomAlertControllerWillDismiss!(controller: self)
}


}
```

Comment: Of course. Thank you so much. I was so stuck in the old ways I didn't even think about this.